# How to show print dialogue box

Tags: java, database, printing

I have been trying to figure out a way to do this, hope someone can help me out.

I have a table populated in my database (MS Access). I know how to retrieve the data from the database but i want to say create a report which a user can print out in paper. I need to know how to add such an option.

It would be awesome if i get this solved!

Thanks!

Comment: Where have you created and displaying your report java/access/swing/webpage?

Comment: See basically its a table in ms access. for eg:
Name, Subject, Marks.

I want to be printed Name - ........
Subject - .........
Marks - ...........

With a jbutton 'PRINT' which when clicked will open 'print dialogue box'

Answer (score 1):

You could save your report in a temp file, i.e. `tempFile`, and then call:

```
    Desktop.getDesktop().print(tempFile);
```